# Return a list of paths to leaf-nodes from a nested list of lists

Tags: python, list, tree

I have a dynamic tree structure that is represented as a list of lists - here is one such example, laid out with whitespace to illustrate the structure:

```
[['first',     
               [0, 'list1'], 
               [1, 'list2'], 
               [2, 'list3']],
 ['second',    
               ['second_subda', 
                      [0, 'tup1'], 
                      [1, 'tup2']],
               ['second_subdb', 
                      [0, 'tup3'], 
                      [1, 'tup4']]],
 ['third',
               ['third_subda',   
                      [0, 'a'],
                      [1, 'b'],
                      [2, 'c'],
                      [3, 
                            ['d',  
                                  [0, 'e'], 
                                  [1, 'f'], 
                                  [2, 
                                        ['g', 
                                               [0, 1], 
                                               [1, 2], 
                                               [2, 3]]]]]]]]
```

And I want to extract from this, all the leaf-nodes, along with the paths required to reach them:

e.g. from the above structure, I want to return:

```
[ ( 'list1', ['first', 0 ] ) , 
  ( 'list2', ['first', 1 ] ) , 
  ( 'list3', ['first', 2 ] ) , 
  ( 'tup1' , ['second',  'second_subda', 0 ] ) ,
  ( 'tup2' , ['second',  'second_subda', 1 ] ) ,
  ( 'tup3' , ['second',  'second_subdb', 0 ] ) ,
  ( 'tup4' , ['second',  'second_subdb', 1 ] ) ,
  ( 'a'    , ['third',   'third_subda',  0 ] ) ,  
  ( 'b'    , ['third',   'third_subda',  1 ] ) ,  
  ( 'c'    , ['third',   'third_subda',  2 ] ) ,  
  ( 'e'    , ['third',   'third_subda',  3  , 'd',  0 ] ) ,  
  ( 'f'    , ['third',   'third_subda',  3  , 'd',  1 ] ) ,  
  (  1     , ['third',   'third_subda',  3  , 'd',  2 , 'g' , 0 ] ) ,  
  (  2     , ['third',   'third_subda',  3  , 'd',  2 , 'g' , 1 ] ) ,  
  (  3     , ['third',   'third_subda',  3  , 'd',  2 , 'g' , 2 ] )]
```

i.e. for each "leaf", I want to extract a tuple consisting of all the leaf value, and a list of all the initial list-entries that describe the unique pathway to arrive at that leaf item. I should be left with a list of these tuples, where the number of items in the list corresponds to the number of leaf nodes within the tree.

I've tried constructing this tree in a module like `networkx` but the overhead of an additional module is overkill for my use-case. I just want to stick to vanilla python code where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
data = [['first', [0, 'list1'], [1, 'list2'], [2, 'list3']], ['second', ['second_subda', [0, 'tup1'], [1, 'tup2']], ['second_subdb', [0, 'tup3'], [1, 'tup4']]], ['third', ['third_subda', [0, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [2, 'c'], [3, ['d', [0, 'e'], [1, 'f'], [2, ['g', [0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]]]]]]]]
def get_paths(d, c = []):
  for a, *b in d:
    if len(b) == 1 and not isinstance(b[0], list):
      yield (b[0], c+[a])
    else:
      yield from get_paths(b, c+[a])

print(list(get_paths(data)))
```

Output:

```
[('list1', ['first', 0]), 
 ('list2', ['first', 1]), 
 ('list3', ['first', 2]), 
 ('tup1', ['second', 'second_subda', 0]), 
 ('tup2', ['second', 'second_subda', 1]), 
 ('tup3', ['second', 'second_subdb', 0]), 
 ('tup4', ['second', 'second_subdb', 1]), 
 ('a', ['third', 'third_subda', 0]), 
 ('b', ['third', 'third_subda', 1]), 
 ('c', ['third', 'third_subda', 2]), 
 ('e', ['third', 'third_subda', 3, 'd', 0]), 
 ('f', ['third', 'third_subda', 3, 'd', 1]), 
 (1, ['third', 'third_subda', 3, 'd', 2, 'g', 0]), 
 (2, ['third', 'third_subda', 3, 'd', 2, 'g', 1]), 
 (3, ['third', 'third_subda', 3, 'd', 2, 'g', 2])]
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it seems lovely and elegant - am I right in thinking that the `a, *b` term in the loop is a means of separating the list into a partition consisting of the [0]th and [1:]th list contents? I don't think I've seen that construction before in quite that way.

Comment: @ThomasKimber You are exactly right. `a, *b` is known as unpacking, whereby `a` is the first element of the element yielded by the iterator, and `b` is `element[1:]`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you can, use a dict of dicts rather than a list of lists for this. Dictionaries have constant lookup times for keys unlike lists which have linear lookup times.

On to your question, any time you are dealing with dynamic trees, recursion is usually the way.

This works with your tree:

```
def get_leaf_paths(children: list, path_prefix:list=[], acc:list=[]):
    for child in children:
        path = path_prefix + [child[0]]
        if isinstance(child[1], list):
            get_leaf_paths(child[1:], path, acc)
        else:
            acc.append(
                (child[1], path)
            )
    return acc

get_leaf_paths(tree)
```

However this is ugly, and for good reason. Python doesn't want you to implement trees like this when the dict structure is more suited. For instance it's not pretty to reference the leaf value by index (`child[1]`), and also containing the node names and children in the same list is questionable (leading to the `child[1:]` iteration over children, which is not descriptive). Calls to `isinstance` are also to be avoided in good python code, but we need it here to check if we have a leaf.

Best practice dictates that leafs should be nodes with `None` as children - this makes checking leaf status easier. If we implement the same with a dict of dicts and `None` children for leaves, the function cleans up to:

```
def get_leaf_paths_dict(tree: dict, path=[], acc=[]):
    for node, children in tree.items():
        if children: # not leaf
            get_leaf_paths(children, path + [node], acc)
        else:
            acc.append((node, path))
    return acc

get_leaf_paths_2(tree)
```

which is much nicer to read. To be clear, for the second to work, the tree must be changed to a dict of dicts, ie:

```
{{'first':  {0: {'list1': None}, 
             1: {'list2': None}, 
             2: {'list3': None},
 {'second': { ... etc.
```

and as an aside, if you build your tree like this you can import it into Networkx with the function `nx.from_dict_of_dicts` and perform all the manipulations the networkx api gives you from there.

Finally, I realise that if you're new to functional programming, both functions I've  given might need some explanation. Recursion on trees works by noting that every child in a tree can itself be viewed as a tree, and so we can save *a lot* of lines of code by having the function call itself and pass along the accumulated list of paths and the current path to append any new paths to.

Edit: I'll even give you the function to convert to a dict of dicts for free (note the similarity):

```
def to_dict_of_dicts(tree, acc={}):
    for child in tree:
        if isinstance(child[1], list):
            acc[child[0]] = to_dict_of_dicts(child[1:])
        else:
            return {child[1] : None}
    return acc

print(to_dict_of_dicts(tree))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - the reason for starting with a list of lists is that my starting point is an arbitrarily complex python object, consisting of nested dicts, lists, tuples and other contents for which I want to build an extraction index based on search terms identified at the leaves. Having built this index, I can search on the 1st element of each tuple, and return the path to find (and edit) the section of the object under revision.